# Why wont /testfor work?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I've been trying to do `/testfor @a [r=5]` for something, but it wont work! It just gives me an error message like "Data tag" something something "Unexpected "[" as first char." I've done the command before and it works, so why won't it work now??

Answer (score 2):

Once again, you have put a space in between the `@a` and the radius selector.

Correct command: `/testfor @a[r=5]`

A redstone comparator coming out of the block will emit a signal when this is true.

Comment: oh my god I seriously did it again xD I feel so dumb lol.
Thanks :P

Answer (score 0):

You put a space in between `@a` and `[r=5]`.

The correct command is this:

```
/testfor @a[r=5]
```

The `"/"` is optional.